# Is there a way to find out how worn out the SSD storage is on an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ssd, flash-memory

I am about to retire an iPhone 6S which has finally gotten a bit too slow for me. Out of curiosity, I'd like to find out how worn out the flash storage / SSD is on the device. I know that on macOS I can use `smartctl` to find out the wear percentage of my SSD drives, so I'm curious if there is something similar for the iPhone?

Comment: Just curious: are you running iOS 15.5? It works fine for me on an iPhone 6S.

Comment: @lhf Yes, latest and greatest. It does work, but I just find it slow and it has gotten worse in the last few months - if I try to 'mark complete' reminders that pop up, it takes several seconds for them to disappear. So more-or-less curious if SSD is a high wear percentage and that might be causing it...

Comment: This is really an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) What you need to find out is why it's running slowly. How full is it? When was the last time you rebooted, or refreshed it completely? How old is the battery? [Mine went through two before I finally swapped it for a new SE]

Comment: @Tetsujin - I agree, but to be honest I am more just interested in knowing the wear percentage of the drive. I know from benchmarks how much slower the 6S is in comparison to an A15 and I know there are services (e.g. COVID exposure) running that don't help. So it is less about debugging, and more curiosity of the SSD since I track this for all my other devices.